# CheckQuery not filtering by TxnDate

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am using the code below to pull Check entities for a given transaction date. However, I am getting checks back with *other* transaction dates than the one I supplied. What is going on?

```
var date = new DateTime(2013, 3, 1);
var context = _qb.CreateContext();
var entries = new List<Check>();

var page = 1;
do
{
    var query = new CheckQuery();
    query.PageNumber = page;
    query.ResultsPerPage = 100;
    query.TxnDate = date;
    var results = query.ExecuteQuery<Check>(context).ToList();
    if (results.Count == 0) break;
    entries.AddRange(results);
    page++;
} while (true);

//entries now contains Checks with TxnDate like '4/30/2013'
```

My end goal is to attempt to get all the transactions for a given week. I can't seem to find a way to do that so I'm instead trying to get each set of entities for the date range to build the complete list. If there is an easier way to essentially get the "Profit and Loss Detail" for a given date-range, please let me know.

Comment: Please post the request/response XML.
http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0055_DevKits/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit/0600_Logging#section_10

Comment: Since I'm just using the C# code I posted to make the request and read the response, how would I get the xml data you're requesting? Is there some sort of logging I can hook into? I guess I missed that in the samples.

Comment: Yes, please enable logging.  I included the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through some of the documentation about Filtering based on Peter's link, I found a reference to including the Extensions namespace which allowed me to specify an operator which made things work as I expected.

```
using Intuit.Ipp.Data.Extensions;
...
query.SpecifyOperatorOption(FilterProperty.TxnDate, FilterOperatorType.EQUALS);
```

For others working with filtering using the built-in ..Query objects, I ran into problems trying to use date range filters. Some objects defaulted to add an .EQUALS operator when you set TxnDate, others did not. For the ones that did (eg JournalEntryQuery) I could not then subsequently do a date range filter using .BEFORE and .AFTER. To get around this I started using the built-in **RestRequestHandler** object instead of Query objects. I couldn't find any documentation on this object, but it is really simple to use if you play around with it and it worked like a charm for my needs.